# why does not Int maxBound work?

Tags: haskell, constructor, int

When I try

```
> Int maxBound
```

in ghci, I get

```
Not in scope: data constructor 'Int'
```

Even if I `import Data.Int`, still the problem persists.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EDIT: The official docs for the function are at http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/Prelude.html#v:maxBound

To begin with, you should be doing

```
Prelude> maxBound :: Int
9223372036854775807
Prelude>
```

If you look at the type signature of `maxBound`:

```
Prelude> :t maxBound
maxBound :: (Bounded a) => a
```

Then `maxBound` is a function that returns something of type `a`, where `a` is `Bounded`. However, it does not accept any parameters. `Int maxBound` means that you are trying to create something with data constructor `Int` and parameter `maxBound`.

For your specific error message, you are trying to use `Int` - which is a type - as a value, resulting in the error you are getting. Importing `Data.Int` won't help.

Comment: A complete aside, linking to zvon is bad practice these days: it is very out of date, and sometimes misleading. Better to link to the Hackage documentation for the Prelude or base library.

Comment: Sorry; it was the first Google link. I'll change it.

Answer (score 7):

That's not valid Haskell.

[`maxBound`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell2010/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3amaxBound) is a constant that defines the maximum element of types that are in [the `Bounded` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell2010/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aBounded):

```
Prelude> :t maxBound
maxBound :: Bounded a => a
```

To get the bound for any particular type, you need to specialize it to a particular type. [Type annotations](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#exp-type-sigs) are given by `::` syntax on expressions, like so:

```
Prelude> maxBound :: Int
9223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if this case (**maxBound**) is not the most elocvent usage of the ***TypeApplications*** GHC compiler option, I found it a bit more suggestive compared with the type annotation options **::** (at least for me as a newly embarked on Haskell boat).

I admit it requires a compilation option/pragma, but it is one of many I have activated by globally in ***~/.ghci*** file. And it's easy to apply!

So, without further ado let's see it in practice. The followings are for me the most common options to enable the TypeApplications compiler option.

1. Enable TypeApplications per GHCI session

```
Prelude> :set -XTypeApplications
Prelude> maxBound @Int
9223372036854775807
Prelude> maxBound @Bool
True
```

1. Enable TypeApplications at directory level or OS user level, by adding in the file **.ghci** the following.

```
:set -XTypeApplications
```

and  then in GHCI prompt

```
Prelude> maxBound @Int
9223372036854775807
```

1. Enable TypeApplications at the Haskell file level by placing the following at the beginning of the file.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
```

**Notes:**

- To disable this option in the GHCI prompt just

```
Prelude> :unset -XTypeApplications
```

- This post is a bit too verbose but it emphasises just on of the many cases this compilation option comes in handy.